# Why is the (android) Human Torch called the Human Torch?

Tags: marvel, names

Before there was the Fantastic Four's human Human Torch, there was the original Human Torch, who was actually an android.

**Does anyone know why the Human Torch (Android) was called the Human Torch when he isn't actually human?**

I'm fine with in- or out-of-universe answers.

Comment: The “Human Torch” is neither!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see from the opening chapter of [Marvel Comics #1](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/10008/marvel_comics_1939_1), he was (inaccurately) dubbed "The *Human* Torch" by his creator; Professor Horton in honour of the fact that he was ***intended to be an exact replica of a human***.

[image]

In later years (and [several reboots later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Torch_(android)#The_Torch)) he would drop the 'human' part and just be known as The Torch.

Comment: For the record, if anyone has a spare (paper) copy of Marvel Comics #1, I'd be happy to take it off their hands for a fiver. I'll even pay for postage.